# Mongo db meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am new to mongo db and meteor. I have a document as the one below:
Calender:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577a09d3e9ac22d62a20ab01"),
    "status_visualizacion" : "visible",
    "status_tipo" : "Pintura",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-07-04T07:01:39.018Z"),
    "usuarios_admin" : [ 
        ObjectId("5773976c201bb491f499c180"), 
        ObjectId("577a03db9da98306f624c3d9"), 
        ObjectId("577a041d9da98306f624c3da"), 
        ObjectId("577a07b7e9ac22d62a20aae9"), 
        ObjectId("577a07c6e9ac22d62a20aaea"), 
        "Ys6fiychXcSfCgWox"
    ],
    "grupo_usuarios" : [ 
        ObjectId("5773976c201bb491f499c180"), 
        ObjectId("577a03db9da98306f624c3d9"), 
        ObjectId("577a041d9da98306f624c3da"), 
        ObjectId("577a07b7e9ac22d62a20aae9"), 
        ObjectId("577a07c6e9ac22d62a20aaea")
    ],
    "calendario_slaves" : [ 
        ObjectId("577b6a0114b9512e1e3f4c10"), 
        ObjectId("577b6a1d14b9512e1e3f4c11"), 
        ObjectId("577b6a2414b9512e1e3f4c12")
    ]
}
```

I want to retrieve all the Id's of all the calendarios_slaves that belongs to this particular Calender in my client side helper in other to use them to query for a particular calendarios_slave. I have tried all I could but all to no result. The code I have presently is this:

```
  Template.testeo.helpers({
    ls: function(){

    var list=Calender.find({status_visualizacion: "visible"});
    var result="";


    list.forEach(function(calender){
      result += calender.calendario_slaves + " ";
    });
    console.log(result);
    console.log("split");

    mySplitResult = result.split(",");
    for ( var i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++ ) {
                mySplitResult2 =mySplitResult[i].split(" ")

           for ( var j = 0; j < mySplitResult2.length; j++ ) {
            myTrozo= mySplitResult2[j];
            console.log(myTrozo);
}
    }
    //console.log(myTrozo);
   return myTrozo;
    }
    });
```

I managed to retrieve all the Id's of all the calendario_slave of this Calender butthey were all in a single line so I implemented the SPLIT to split them using a while loop but the problem now is that I cant access SPLIT result (myTrozo) outside the for loop, the first console.log(myTrozo) displays what i need but I don't know how to manage it return myTrozo.
Could any one with more experience help me out if there's anything am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items = Meteor.subscribe('Calendar');

var itemsCursor = items.find({ status_visualizacion: "visible" });

while ( itemCursor.hasNext() ) {
  item = itemCursor.next();
  for (i = 0; i < item.calendario_slaves.length; i++) {
    console.log(item.calendario_slaves[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.concat` to concatenate arrays. You don't need to convert to strings and split.

```
Template.testeo.helpers({
  ls() {
    const result=[];
    Calender.find({status_visualizacion: "visible"}).forEach(e => {
      if ( e.calendario_slaves && e.calendario.slaves.length ){ // guard against missing/empty
        results.concat(e.calendario_slaves);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
});
```